# how to setup rails Authenticity Token to work with multiple domains?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an app that uses subdomains as account handles (myaccount.domain.com) and I have my sessions configured to work across the sub-domains like so:

```
config.action_controller.session = {:domain => '.domain.com'}
```

In addition to the subdomain a user can input a real domain name when they are creating their account.  My Nginx config is setup to watch for *.com *.net etc, and this is working to serve out the pages.

The problem comes when a site visitor submits a comment form on a custom domain that was input by the user. The code is throwing an "Invalid AuthenticityToken" exception.  I'm 99% sure this is because the domain the user is on isn't specified as the domain in the config.action_controller.session.  Thus the authenticity token isn't getting matched up because Rails can't find their session.

So, the question is:  Can you set config.action_controller.session to more than 1 domain, and if so can you add / remove from that value at runtime without restarting the app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to this question here: http://codetunes.com/2009/04/17/dynamic-cookie-domains-with-racks-middleware/

This solution worked for me because my app was running on Rails 2.3.5, which uses Rack.  The request comes from web server, goes through middleware layers and enters the application.  So this middleware layer detects the host with which the application is accessed and sets cookie domain for the request. Here it is:

```
# app/middlewares/set_cookie_domain.rb
class SetCookieDomain
  def initialize(app, default_domain)
    @app = app
    @default_domain = default_domain
  end

  def call(env)
    host = env["HTTP_HOST"].split(':').first
    env["rack.session.options"][:domain] = custom_domain?(host) ? ".#{host}" : "#{@default_domain}"
    @app.call(env)
  end

  def custom_domain?(host)
    domain = @default_domain.sub(/^\./, '')
    host !~ Regexp.new("#{domain}$", Regexp::IGNORECASE)
  end
end


# turn it on in environment.rb
config.load_paths += %W( #{RAILS_ROOT}/app/middlewares )


# production.rb
config.middleware.use "SetCookieDomain", ".example.org"
```

.example.org is the default domain that will be used unless the application is accessed via custom domain (like site.com), we give it different values depending on environment (production/staging/development etc).

```
# tests/integration/set_cookie_domain_test.rb (using Shoulda and Webrat)
require 'test_helper'

class SetCookieDomainTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest

  context "when accessing site at example.org" do
    setup do
      host! 'example.org'
      visit '/'
    end

    should "set cookie_domain to .example.org" do
      assert_equal '.example.org', @integration_session.controller.request.session_options[:domain]
    end
  end

  context "when accessing site at site.com" do
    setup do
      host! 'site.com'
      visit '/'
    end

    should "set cookie_domain to .site.com" do
      assert_equal '.site.com', @integration_session.controller.request.session_options[:domain]
    end
  end

  context "when accessing site at site.example.org" do
    setup do
      host! 'site.example.org'
      visit '/'
    end

    should "set cookie_domain to .example.org" do
      assert_equal '.example.org', @integration_session.controller.request.session_options[:domain]
    end
  end

end
```